# How to remove dependent records in angularfire 0.8.2

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

I would like to know how to delete firebase record fields which are related to another field.

```
$scope["delete"] = function(id) {
  $scope.clubs = fbutil.syncArray("club");
  $scope.clubs.$remove(item);
  $scope.removeClubUser = fbutil.syncArray("clubuser/" + id + "/" + user.uid);
  $scope.removeClubUsers.$remove(user.uid);
  $scope.removeUserClub = fbutil.syncArray("userclub/" + user.uid + "/" + id);
  $scope.removeUserClub.$remove(id);
};
```

Now I dont know if this circular structure is the best approach but that way I can always keep track which user is in which club given the user and club id 
$scope.clubs.$remove works just as expected but removeClubUser and removeUserClub do not.
Why is that and how would it work?
Thanks Sven

Comment: You probably don't want `id` in `removeUserClub`, as the $remove function does not take an id, but either an item or an index. You can use `$getRecord()` if you have a key and need to switch between the two.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you kato for pointing this out to me that $keyAt the index in the array does indeed provide  the necessary id to be able to find the exact location of the record. 
Here how I could remove all the dependant records.

```
$scope["delete"] = function(index) {

  $scope.clubs = fbutil.syncArray("club");
  $scope.clubs.$remove(index);

  var id = $scope.clubs.$keyAt(index);

  $scope.removeClubUser = fbutil.ref("clubuser/" + id + "/" + user.uid);
  $scope.removeClubUser.remove();

  $scope.removeUserClub = fbutil.ref("userclub/" + user.uid + "/" + id);
  $scope.removeUserClub.remove();
};
```